# Deleting a row based on value in another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-forms

I sell hardware and I'm using Google Sheets as a database. Using a Google Form I store serial numbers and other information. 
Now I want an easy way to remove products from this database. I made a second Google Form where I simply scan the serial number and store this in another sheet. 
I would like this sheet to automatically look for a matching serial number in the database, and then remove the entire row this serial number is in, therefor deleting the corresponding product from the database. I will provide screenshots to hopefully make it easier to understand.

```
function onEdit(e) {

  try {
    var ss = e.source; 
    var s = ss.getActiveSheet();

    if (s.getName() == 'DeleteFromDatabase' &&   
        e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.columnEnd == 2 &&  
        e.range.rowStart == e.range.rowEnd ) {  
      checkCellValue(e); 
    }
  } catch (error) { Logger.log(error); }
}

function checkCellValue(e) {
    e.source.getSheetByName("DeleteFromDatabase").deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
    e.source.getSheetByName("Database").deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
//This only deletes the value inserted into column B and the value in the corresponding row in the other sheet. 
}
```

Comment: this edit function you want to run when google form's response is getting stored in sheet?

Answer (score 0):

To make something automatically when a form response is submitted, instead an on edit simple trigger use an on form submit installable trigger.